# Glassfish can't run on virtual private server

Tags: java, performance, configuration, glassfish

I have an install of glassfish 4 on centOs 6.7 hosted at 1 & 1. 
The config is the following : 
1 VCPU 
1GO RAM 
40GO SSD

My max numproc is 160 and whenever I run glassfish and do some operations, I reach the maximum and the server crashes.

I've followed oracle performance tunning guide but not much success with it. 
Do I need a server with a config more powerful ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the server itself crash or is it the Glassfish container that crashes? If its Glassfish that crashes can you check the Glassfish log to see whether any errors or stacktraces are recorded please?

Comment: Hello @PaulH, it is the server that crashes, it cannot open anymore threads and then I cannot execute anymor actions SSH/glassfish. I can only restart the server from the virtuozzo panel.